# I want to select the largest valid number from an array

Tags: javascript

Hey I am writing code for an assignment and I'm stuck. My problem is I want to find the largest valid number within an array that meets the conditions which are, that the number is between [0,500] and divisible by 5 or 3. This what I have so far:

```
var numlist =[];
var count = 0 ;
var bignum;


while (count >= 0) { 
    bignum = Number(prompt("Enter Number"));

    if (bignum == 12345){   
        break;
    }

    if (bignum > 500 || bignum < 0){
        document.write("No data to Print");
        continue;
    }

    if (!(bignum % 3 === 0 || bignum % 5 === 0)){
        document.write("No data to Print");
        continue;
    }

    numlist = Math.max(bignum);
    bignum = numlist;

    var loop;

    for (loop = 0; loop <= 10; loop++){
        value = bignum * loop;
        document.write(bignum + " X " + loop + " = " + value + "<br />");
    }
}
```

Here is the assignment and an example of the code
[image: prompt]
[image: code]

Can someone help me please?

Comment: @driconmax please read this meta question about homework questions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @MarcMarchiavelli it's ok posting homework questions when you at least tryied (this is your case).

Comment: If you don't try by your self to solve it, you are not going lo learn ever.... The problem that he is facing is part of what he needs to practice...

Comment: He's trying... the code shows the OP has done something. Now we need to point it to the right direction. I'm taking a look here.

Answer (score 0):

Here, this is one way to do it. I tryied to change it the least I could so you could do this "your way". Please study this code a bit and fell free to ask if you don't understand something.

```js
var numlist = [];
var bignum;

// get the number and populate the array
while (true) { // you don't need a var if you want an infinite loop
    bignum = Number(prompt("Enter Number"));

    if (bignum == 12345) {
        break;
    }

    if (bignum > 500 || bignum < 0) {
        continue;
    }

    if (!(bignum % 3 == 0 || bignum % 5 == 0)) {
        continue;
    }

    numlist.push(bignum); // push method in an array includes a value
}
    
if (numlist.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = "No data to Print";
} else {    
    var max = -Infinity;
    for(var ix = 0; ix<numlist.length; ix++) {
     if (numlist[ix] > max) max = numlist[ix];
    }
    
    var content = '';
    for (var loop = 0; loop <= 10; loop++) {
        value = max * loop;
        content += max + " X " + loop + " = " + value + "<br />";    
    }
    document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = content;
}
```

```html
<div id="res"></div>
```

Here is a more advanced version of it for you to study when you are better at javascript:   :)

```js
var numlist = [], bignum;
while ((bignum = Number(prompt("Enter Number"))) != 12345) 
    ((bignum > 0) && (bignum < 500)) && (!(bignum % 3) || !(bignum % 5)) && 
     numlist.push(bignum);

var max = Math.max(...numlist)
document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = 
    numlist.length && [...Array(11).keys()].reduce((p, _ign, ix)=>
        p += max + " X " + ix + " = " + (max * ix) + "<br />", '') || 'No data to Print';
```

```html
<div id="res"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This really helps.

Comment: If it was useful to you please upvote/accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Few pointers. Start by breaking code to smaller function. This will make your code more reusable. Second, you can use `Math.max.apply(numList)`. Its faster than loop. Third, since this is an assignment, we can assume that OP might not know about spread operator(`...`). Fourth, in second approach, its better to use `array.filter`

Comment: Good points. I invite you to make your own answer with them so we can learn more. :) About being an assignment,notice that I made a "simple version" for the OP to use and an "advanced" version for study.